# How to assign values to different lables(legends) of my dataset of stacked bar chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I want to display a stacked bar chart that displays data for 5 zones. Each zone has 3 status- 'Completed','In Progress' and 'Waiting'. I am hitting an api which is giving me the following response -

```
{
  "Zone 1": [
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Completed",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "In Progress",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Waiting",
      "count": 0
    }
  ],
  "Zone 2": [
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Completed",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "In Progress",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Waiting",
      "count": 0
    }
  ],
  "Zone 3": [
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Completed",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "In Progress",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Waiting",
      "count": 0
    }
  ],
  "Zone 4": [
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Completed",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "In Progress",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Waiting",
      "count": 2
    }
  ],
  "Zone 5": [
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Completed",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "In Progress",
      "count": 0
    },
    {
      "mtstatusName": "Waiting",
      "count": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I need the count of each zone to get displayed in my bar chart. Each zone on the chart represents values for Completed, In progress and Waiting depending upon the count.

Earlier I was giving hard coded data so it was working. But now I have to fetch values from this json. Attaching my code here. Kindly let me know how can i give values to all the three parameters for all the 5 zones.I have given empty array to 'data' for each label. I have to do this.setState for each of these arrays which I am unable to do.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            metricsAndStatus: {},
            zoneName:"",
            status: "",
            dataElements:{
                labels: ['Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3', 'Zone 4', 'Zone 5'],
                datasets: [
                {
                        data: [],
                        label: 'Completed',
                        backgroundColor: '#bad96b'
                },
                  {
                    data: [],
                    label: 'In Progress',
                   backgroundColor: '#8ad0f9',

                  },
                  {
                    data: [],
                    label: 'Waiting',
                    backgroundColor: '#ffda78'
                  }, 
                ]
              }
         }
    }
    triggerAssetMetricsData = () => {
        fetch('api ')//hitting api here
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log( response[Object.keys(response)[0]][0].count)
            this.setState({
            metricsAndStatus:response,
            zoneName: Object.keys(response),
           })
         })
        ;
       }
        componentDidMount = () => {
        this.triggerAssetMetricsData();

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through your data. My solutions works when your status always come in the same order (like they do in your example). If not, then you have to perform an additional check.

https://jsbin.com/zunimifidi/1/edit?js,output

```
chartData.labels = Object.keys(data)

for (let i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
  console.log(status[i])
  let newDataset = {}
  newDataset.label = status[i]
  newDataset.backgroundColor = colors[status[i]]
  newDataset.data = []
  for (let idx in data) {  
    let cData = data[idx]
    newDataset.data.push(cData[i].count)
  }
  chartData.datasets.push(newDataset)
}
```